# dynamically create user name

Tags: jquery, split

I want to create a username based on the name of a person with jquery.

I have no idea how to start, I was thinking about split the name, get the first letter from each part and concatenate with the last name. But I don't know how to do it if the name has lots of words.

For example my name

```
'First' -> username 'first'
'First Second' -> username 'fsecond'
'First Second Third' -> username 'fsthird'
```

code (only do the first case, but what if there are many middle name?)

```
function createUsername(fullName) {

   var piece;
   var size;

   piece = fullName.split(' ');
   size = piece.length;
   if(size == 1)
     $("#userName").val(piece[0]);
}


<input type='text' onKeyUp = 'createUsername(this.value)'/>
<input type='text' name='userName' id='userName' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
function createUsername(name) {
    return name.split(" ").map(function(v, i, a) {
        return i !== (a.length - 1) ? v[0] : v;
    }).join().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the last name of your split array and iterate over it like so:

```
function createUsername(fullName) {

   var piece;
   var size;

   piece = fullName.split(' ');
   size = piece.length;
   var name = piece[size-1].toLowerCase();
   for (var i = size -2; i > 0; i--) {
       name = piece[i][0].toLowerCase() + name;
   }
   $("#userName").val(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, split the string based on a space to get the user's name, but then after that you need to loop to get you the first letters of all the names before the last name.

```js
function createUsername(fullName) {

  var piece,
      username = [];

  piece = fullName.split(' ');

  if (piece.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
      if (i < piece.length - 1) {
        username.push(piece[i].charAt(0));
      } else {
        username.push(piece[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    username.push(piece[0]);
  }

  $("#userName").val(username.join(""));
}
```

[Here's a CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpKsy)

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated ; added processing of names including four or more words

Try (v2)

```
  function createUserName(fullName) {
    var s = fullName.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+/g)
    , l = s.length, _s = "", y = -1;
      do { _s += s[++y][0] } while (_s.length < l -1);
          return l > 1 ? _s + s[l -1] : fullName;
  };
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/yfyogoqd/

Comment: It works for names with 3 words, but what if names with four or more? Amit Joki's answer has worked properly. Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: See updated post. Added piece for processing of names including four or more words . Happy to help , if able :) Thank you